# Relabel "PersonEmail" Field in Accounts

Tags: apex, person-accounts

- How can I relabel the "PersonEmail" field in Account?
- I am trying to update this in "Rename Tabs and Labels -> Account -> Fields. But its not showing the Email field itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Label: Email (API : PersonEmail)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it, looks like I need to update "Contacts" field in this case.